# How to fire a custom event from another plugin?

Tags: events

I have some questions about events. I want to fire a custom event from another plugin. The event handler is in **MyHelpers_PostService.php** (plugin A).

```
public function onSavePost(Event $event)
{
    $this->raiseEvent('onSavePost', $event);
}
```

My init() method (plugin B):

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('myHelpers_Post.savePost', function(Event $event)
    {
       // delete a cache key 
       craft()->pluginB->clearCache('forum-home-desktop');
    });
}
```

This is my first time working on Craft events, so please bear with me. I tested this by saving a new Helpers Post on the front-end and nothing happens.

The **clearCache()** method is just using Craft's **deleteCachesByKey()**;

1. Is **myHelpers_Post.savePost** correct?
2. What else do I need to make this work?
3. How do I test this properly? Can I use Craft::dd() inside the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**myHelpers_Post.savePos**t was wrong. It should have been **myHelpers_*p*ost.savePost**. It's okay to delete this question.

Comment: It's good to keep the question in, in case someone else comes across a similar problem. Just accept your own answer as the correct one!